# Getting Facebook Messenger Page_Access_Token in .env

Tags: javascript, windows, facebook

According to Facebook Guide line, I was told to create a .env file to store the Page_Access_Token
The content in .env is:

```
PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

and we have an app.js that included:

```
const PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN = process.env.PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN;
```

However, when I console.log(process.env.PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN); it returns me an undefined

Can advise how to fix this problem?

P.S. I am using windows and ngrok to test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.env` without any configurations or tools does nothing, unless your told your app to, this is just a basic file.

However if you really want to use a `.env` to store your environment variables, you may need something like this [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)